# youtube data api multiple pages

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Youtube Data api here:
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples

Specifically, I am looking at:
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py

In that file there is:

```
 search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.max_results
).execute()
```

However, the maximum result is 50. Is ther ea way I can change the parameter to youtube.search() to get results 51 -100, 101 - 150, etc? I can't seem to find it in the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pageToken parameter to get the next pages:

> pageToken string
>
> The pageToken parameter identifies a specific page in the result set that should be returned. In an API response, the nextPageToken and prevPageToken properties identify other pages that could be retrieved.

Next pages id(`nextPageToken`) is returned from the first response, using that id to get next page.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": etag,
 "nextPageToken": string,
 "prevPageToken": string,
 "regionCode": string,
 "pageInfo": {
   "totalResults": integer,
   "resultsPerPage": integer
 },
 "items": [
   search Resource
 ]
```

}

More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Comment: Yes, that's if I create the Get string directly and submit a request. What about through the python package though?